# old session in my website is clear after get signed_request from facebook

Tags: facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, session-variables

Sessions are used in my website, but then when I open an facebook app which redirect to my website, I found out that old sessions are clear.

I assumed that after getting the signed_request, facebook clear my old sessions. Am i right for this assumption ?

The problem is that I want to keep my old session even if i have request a signed_request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be happening because the facebook app doesn’t send a csrf token.

You can fix this by adding removing the `protect_from_forgery` callback on the facebook app’s action.

Add `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` to the controller that facebook apps request or remove `protect_from_forgery` from application_controller.rb

I have also posted this on my blog here [http://wowcode.wordpress.com/](http://wowcode.wordpress.com/2012/09/06/facebook-signed-request-losing-session-in-rails/)